# How to get default font of UITabBarItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitabbaritem

How to get font default of `UITabBarItem`. Please help if you can get it.
Because I want to repeat with the default value. Font Size `UITabBarItem` changed that I do not know why.

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: fontDault!], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to get the current title text attributes before you set your own attributes. Save that dictionary for use when you wish to reset to those original attributes.

```
let defaultAttributes = UITabBarItem.appearance().titleTextAttributes(for: .normal)
```

Then set your own attributes when needed.

When you wish to reset the attributes, do:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(defaultAttributes, for: .normal)
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks you

Comment: seems to return nil unless it's been set previously?